# Why is the list item for Autocomplete creates the DOM elements outside of the root div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In React, i assume everything renders into the root div (div id="root") using,

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have an Autocomplete component and as I type in the Autocomplete input box, the dropdown falls down and when I inspect the dropdown list items, it is seen that the DOM elements for the list item div are just created outside of the root div, why?

[image: see the image here]

Below is my App component code

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import styles from './App.module.css';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

const App = () => {


  const colors = [
    'Red',
    'Orange',
    'Yellow',
    'Green',
    'Blue',
    'Purple',
    'Black',
    'White',
  ];

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={styles.Grandparent}>    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classic
      .......
      <div className={styles.Parent}>
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
          .......
        <div className={styles.Child}>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
              <AutoComplete
                floatingLabelText="Type 'r', case insensitive"
                filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
                dataSource={colors}
              />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            <div className={styles.Sibling}>I am his sibling</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Very difficult to help you without a reproducible example.

Comment: probably we should guess what is in this autocomplete

Comment: This dropdown list items is probably generated using `javascript` and has a position absolute. Don't really matter where he is placed in this case. The library that you use probably append it to `body`

Comment: Cannot really understand what are you trying to achive here, and whether the drop down is coming in from your component or its the Chrome's Drop-down.

Comment: It depends on the internal working of the Autocomplete library that you are using. Perhaps it is (in jQuery terms) $('body').append('<div>Autocomplete component</div>'). You can check the documentation of the library to see if you can pass a DOM ID to render the Autocomplete component

Comment: @damnitrahul Its a dropdown coming from MaterialUI's Autocomplete component.

Comment: @johannchopin and jimmy, I guess you are correct, I assumed that even if it is rendered later, it would go into the root div as React says to render the complete App inside root div, did not think of a case where DOM elements could be added to the DOM's body also according to the implementation in the Autocomplete component.

Comment: ask component authors (on github) for details - probably was an issue related to this resolved by moving it outside of the main tree